# Multiple layouts for physical keyboard on Android 7

Tags: android, keyboard, android-7.0-nougat, bluetooth-keyboard

I have LineageOS 14.1, and the menu with keyboard layouts for physical keyboard allows you to choose only one language (no multiple choice). How can I choose multiple languages?

Now I have Gboard keyboard, but the problem doesn't depend on keyboard type.
[image]
[image]

Comment: could you describe your issue more clear?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Maybe looking at the source would help out, however it might be Lineage/Stock android limitation. I have the same problem with Motorola device, however a Samsung tablet supports correctly multiple different layouts for the physical/hardware keyboard.

Comment: Same in stock Android. Any solution ?